# Узнать количество повторений объектов в массиве json

Tags: javascript, json

Имею массив:

```
[{"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":1,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false},
{"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false},
{"boost":"mass","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false}]
```

Как узнать, сколько раз повторяются объекты в нём?

Comment: @Igor а как ещё?

Comment: Еще можно показать Ваши попытки "через цикл".

Comment: @Igor дальше запутался http://jsfiddle.net/ajbc1sfw/1/
Друг пытался https://hastebin.com/eqifehepix.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var json = [
  {"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"mass","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":2,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":1,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"xp","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false},
  {"boost":"mass","x":3,"time":24,"activate":false}
];

function getUnique(arr) {
  var i, j, res = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i].boost == res[j].obj.boost && 
          arr[i].x == res[j].obj.x && 
          arr[i].time == res[j].obj.time && 
          arr[i].activate == res[j].obj.activate) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (j == res.length)
      res.push({ obj: arr[i], count: 1 });
    else
      res[j].count++;
  }
  return res;
}

var unique = getUnique(json);
console.log("# of unique objects =", unique.length);
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Не совсем. Вы, получается, узнали количество одинаковых объектов только одного объекта, а надо у всех. Надеюсь, поняли)

Comment: Во, теперь то, что нужно. Спасибо большое за помощь!